# Generic pattern matching and type erasure

Tags: scala, generics, types, pattern-matching

The goal is to write creator function, define what kind of message actor can receive, and match this kind of message inside actor.
So i want to specify that my expected message is of type X (i know this type only when i call create function)

I have very simple code:

```
import akka.actor.Actor.Receive

def create[X]():Receive = {
  case msg:X =>
}
```

This code gives me the following error: "abstract type pattern X is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure"

I know what is type erasure, but i can't find any solution for this problem.

Comment: Have you seen http://daily-scala.blogspot.ca/2010/01/overcoming-type-erasure-in-matching-1.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ClassTag will pretty much handle this:

```
def create[X](implicit tag: ClassTag[X]): Receive = {
  case msg if msg.getClass == tag.runtimeClass =>
}
```

Note though that if your message type is itself affected by type erasure, this will fail. For instance, `create[List[String]]` will still accept a `List[Int]`. I don't think there's a way around this since that info is completely gone at runtime.

Comment: Simply `def create[X : ClassTag]: Receive = {
  case msg: X =>
}` will work as well

Comment: Thank you, This is exactly what i was searching for